# Приемник, который срабатывает на запуск любого приложения

Tags: android-sdk, android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как создать в моем приложении `BroadcastReceiver`, который будет реагировать на запуск любого приложения? При этом после его срабатывания нужно еще вытянуть названия главного пакета запущенного приложения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам необходимо перехватывать запуск чужих приложений - то broadcast receiver тут не подойдет, запуск приложения никак не оповещает систему об этом. Для перехвата запуска своих приложений нужно при запуске пробросить intent.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да, к сожалению через broadcast receiver нельзя. Один из способов это просматривать список апущенных приложений с некоторым интервалом и сравнивать эти списки, таким образом определяя, какое приложения запустилось.

Comment: не за что ) да, ваше решение как вариант